# iTunes multiple users

Tags: app-store-connect, itunes

I want to authorize another user to use my iTunes account (Basically, I want him to be able to purchase music on my behalf - my money - his music selection).

What are my options here? I do not want to necessarily share my apple ID password.

Thanks

Comment: Maybe not - but you make Apple Tech Support look smart...Do you know the answer or not...????

Comment: Whether I know the answer or not is irrelevant. Your question is offtopic for this site.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

*Even though this question is so off-topic I want to help you:*

You can create a family including you and him. You would be the parent while he would be the child. 
There is no other option I know of.

Hope that helps :)